# Group data by category

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an array of objects and each object has an array of categories. The category can be repeated. I want to group this data by each category and display them one under the other with the category as a title.

Imagine I have

```
[
  {
   title: 'Title 1',
   id: '1',
   categories: ['food']
  },
  {
   title: 'Title 2',
   id: '2',
   categories: ['cat']
  },
  {
   title: 'Title 3',
   id: '3',
   categories: ['food', 'cat']
  },
  {
   title: 'Title 4',
   id: '4',
   categories: ['sky']
  },
  {
   title: 'Title 5',
   id: '5',
   categories: ['cat', 'sky']
  },
]
```

In this case in the `Food` section, I should have `Title 1` and `Title 2` etc.

Does anyone know how to group this data? Thanks!

Comment: Provide an example of how the final result (object/array) should look like.

Comment: @DVN-Anakin something like this https://codepen.io/nisag131/pen/OJmvXVQ?editors=0010

So the data need to be grouped and displayed by category. Each category is title and beneath the title I should display related items.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```js
let input = [
  {
   title: 'Title 1',
   id: '1',
   categories: ['food']
  },
  {
   title: 'Title 2',
   id: '2',
   categories: ['cat']
  },
  {
   title: 'Title 3',
   id: '3',
   categories: ['food', 'cat']
  },
  {
   title: 'Title 4',
   id: '4',
   categories: ['sky']
  },
  {
   title: 'Title 5',
   id: '5',
   categories: ['cat', 'sky']
  },
];

function findTitles(category) {
  let result = [];
  input.forEach(val => {
     if (val.categories.includes(category)) result.push(val.title);
  })
  return result;
}

console.log(findTitles("food"))
```

I'm returning an array of titles passing the category to `findTitles`. `findTitles` function iterates on input array finding a `categories` that contains the category.

**EDIT:** This is the version with all categories:

```js
let input = [
   {
    title: 'Title 1',
    id: '1',
    categories: ['food']
   },
   {
    title: 'Title 2',
    id: '2',
    categories: ['cat']
   },
   {
    title: 'Title 3',
    id: '3',
    categories: ['food', 'cat']
   },
   {
    title: 'Title 4',
    id: '4',
    categories: ['sky']
   },
   {
    title: 'Title 5',
    id: '5',
    categories: ['cat', 'sky']
   },
 ];
 
 function findTitles(categories) {
   let result = [];
   for (let i = 0; i < categories.length; i++){
      let resultObj = {};
      resultObj.category = categories[i];
      resultObj.items = [];
       input.forEach(val => {
         if (val.categories.includes(categories[i])) {
            resultObj.items.push({"title": val.title, "id": val.id});
         }
      })
      result.push(resultObj);
   }
     
   return result;
 }

 console.log(findTitles(['food', 'cat', 'sky']))
```

Comment: Can you make an example instead of passing a hardcoded category name to pass an array of all categories? Then `findTitles` function returns all data.

Comment: This is ok but I need this structure https://codepen.io/nisag131/pen/GRmxbxQ?editors=0010

Comment: @user15168120 I updated my answer with structure you need (see second snippet).

Answer (score 0):

Working DEMO:

```js
var myArr = [
  {
   title: 'Title 1',
   id: '1',
   categories: ['food']
  },
  {
   title: 'Title 2',
   id: '2',
   categories: ['cat']
  },
  {
   title: 'Title 3',
   id: '3',
   categories: ['food', 'cat']
  },
  {
   title: 'Title 4',
   id: '4',
   categories: ['sky']
  },
  {
   title: 'Title 5',
   id: '5',
   categories: ['cat', 'sky']
  },
];

function myFun(arr) {
    var uniqueCats = [];
    var catsObj = {};
    var finalArr = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var item = arr[i]; 
        var cats = item.categories;
        var title = item.title;
        var id = item.id;

        for (var j = 0; j < cats.length; j++) {
            var cat = cats[j];

            if (uniqueCats.indexOf(cat) < 0) {
                uniqueCats.push(cat); //console.log(uniqueCats);
                catsObj[cat] = [];
            } 

            catsObj[cat].push({
                'title': title,
                'id': id
            });
        }
    }

    for(var key in catsObj) {
        finalArr.push({
            "category": key,
            "items": catsObj[key]
        });
    }

    return finalArr;
}

console.log(myFun(myArr));
```

Comment: @user15168120 OK, tick my answer as the right answer to your question

Comment: I will as soon as I am allowed to do that